# Why “Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size' byte s of storage” exception just happened in parts of the slaves

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

We have a MySQL replication composed of one master and 5 slaves, and we just find three of the slaves met the following errors and both max_binlog_cache_size and binlog_cache_size are the same to all of the nodes in the cluser and the binlog format is "row". My question is: Why the master and the other two slaves didnt have the exception? What the possibles this situation happened?

> "Could not execute Update_rows event on table xxxxx; Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size' bytes of storage; increase this mysqld variable and try again, Error_code: 1197; handler error HA_ERR_RBR_LOGGING_FAILED; the event's master log mysql-bin.223903, end_log_pos 2326335819, Error_code: 1197"

Comment: Which "cluster"?  I guess not NDB Cluster,  InnoDB Cluster?  Galera Cluster?

Comment: just master&slave replication

Comment: Are the configurations (my.cnf) identical except for server_id?

Comment: sorry for late reply, we are collecting the info from DBA ,and response here just we get  it.

Comment: @RickJames we check the my.cnf  all of them are the same except for server_id

Comment: What is the value of `max_binlog_cache_size`?  (It defaults to an huge value.)  Let's see the query.  What OS is on the Replica?

Comment: max_binlog_cache_size=2G ,OS is  CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Comment: 64-bit OS and 64-bit MySQL?  How much RAM?

Comment: yes, both 64-bit , hardware info are 32c, 128GB, PCIE-SSD

Comment: I don't think this is relevant, but is `tmpdir` in a separate disk partition?  (I would expect a different error message in that case.)

Comment: tmpdir  and data in the same  disk partition and directory.